# Is volatile required if the accessing thread is created by the same thread that previously assigned the variables?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile

```
class MyClass {
    private int value;

    private void someFunction()
    {
        // value will never be assigned anywhere else while the thread is running
        this.value = 10;

        // start thread that reads value
    }
}
```

Does this requires a volatile or is the thread guaranteed to see the latest value?

Comment: Can the thread that you are starting change the value, or will it only read it?

Comment: If the value never changes after the thread is created then you shouldn't need to make it `volatile`. However, if the value is changed (even if the change is made by the parent thread) then it should be declared `volatile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this requires a volatile or is the thread guaranteed to see the latest value?

No, `volatile` is not required.  That Java language definition says that the thread that is created will see all updates made by the creating thread before `start()` is called.

See [Synchronization Order (JLS 17.4.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4).  To quote:

> - An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in the thread it starts.

Obviously, if the value is updated after the `start()` or if the new thread makes changes to the value that the starting thread needs to see then memory synchronization is needed.

The same holds true if you call `thread.join()`.  Any updates made by thread that was joined with are seen by the caller after the `join()` returns.